# How check steps in unit test with Spring 5 Reactor WebFlux?

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm migrating from imperative to reactive mode, and I'm having a hard time testing my mocks callback in a reactive way. Is it possible in a service class for example to check if the mocks were invoked?

```
TransactionId transactionId = authorizerApplicationService.newPaymentAuthorization(
            new PaymentTransactionCommand(
                    OPERATION_ID,
                    TAX_ID));

final ArgumentCaptor<Transaction> argumentsTransaction = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Transaction.class);

verify(repository, times(2)).save(argumentsTransaction.capture());

final Transaction transaction = argumentsTransaction.getValue();

verify(iamServicePort).authenticate(...));

verify(antiFraudServicePort).checkCustomerSituation(...);

verify(paymentGatewayServicePort, times(0)).authorize(...);

assertEquals(transactionId,         transaction.transactionId());
assertEquals(Money.of(100, "BRL"),  transaction.amount());
```

In reactive form:

```
StepVerifier.create(authorizerApplicationService.newPaymentAuthorization(
            new PaymentTransactionCommand(
                    OPERATION_ID,
                    TAX_ID)))
      .expectNext(OPERATION_ID)
       //I need to check here if the mocks were invoked
      .verifyComplete();
```

taking into consideration that all my external services return Mono of Void, how can I do the call verification?